# ASP.NET: Having common Page title in master page with each page adding page-specific title?

Tags: asp.net, master-pages, contentplaceholder, page-title, html-title

My master page looks like:

```
<head runat="server">
    <title>
        <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="PageTitlePlaceHolder" runat="server" />
    </title>
```

Content pages look like:

```
<asp:Content ID="TitleContent1"
     ContentPlaceHolderID="PageTitlePlaceHolder" runat="Server">
    My Page
</asp:Content>
```

This works by placing the content page specific title on the page ("My Page" in this example).  Now I want to add a global prefix to the title in my master page for the site name.  So I want:

```
<head runat="server">
    <title>
        Example.com:
        <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="PageTitlePlaceHolder" runat="server" />
    </title>
```

However, when I do this content pages are still rendered without "Example.com" in the tile, it's like it's ignored.

Why is this happening and how can I achieve this?

Answer (score 3):

Try this in the code behind of the MasterPage:

```
void MasterPage_PreRender(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Page.Title = "Example.com - " + Page.Title;
}
```

Comment: It doesn't work.  Stepping through the code, when executing this line, the Page.Title property is blank

Comment: Try moving down the page lifecycle of the MasterPage ... is the property blank in the MasterPage_Load ?

Comment: Think about what you're doing here.  You're essentially saying Page.Title = Page.Title.  You need to reference the page content in the content placeholder, like so:

    `Page.Title = "My Website Name - " + MyContentPlaceHolder.Page.Title`

Put that in your master page Page_load event.

Answer (score 2):

Remove the title tag from the master page and use the code Martin provided.  Now in your content pages set the title in the Page tag at the top of the file like so:

```
<%@ Page ... Title="Contact" %>
```

Answer (score 2):

The work around I found most acceptable is to use multiple `ContentPlaceHolder` controls.

```html
<head runat="server">
    <title>
        <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="cphMasterTitle" runat="server">Example.com: </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
        <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="cphSubtitle" runat="server" />
    </title>
</head>
```

Note that any other content inside `<title>`, including whitespace, is stripped away. Any spacing between the `ContentPlaceHolder` content needs to be done inside the controls.

I've also used `<asp:Literal runat="server">Example.com: </asp:Literal>` when I don't want to expose a placeholder to the content pages.

Comment: Frustrating, as Hockey Sticks, but double CPH got the Duct-Tape Solution.  There has got to be a better solution.

Answer (score 0):

remove the **"runat="server""**  but i'm not sure,try it

```
<head>
    <title>
        Example.com:
        <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="PageTitlePlaceHolder" runat="server" />
    </title>
```

Answer (score 0):

Two options.
one is remove `runat=server` from `<head>`  (jefferydu)

Two is using  the Page.Title as string. (Martin)

I prefer to use a object I wrote somewhere that add also Title for facebook, description for search engines, etc for any page I used. This object stores the page title in three strings- one before, one is page title, one after.

Answer (score 0):

in the master Page, Put

```
    <title>websitename.com -<%: Page.Title.ToString() %> </title>
```

where websitename.com is the domain name of the website.

and then in Each Content page , put a title.