# Creating a sub-title with a Master Page and ContentPlaceHolder

Tags: asp.net, master-pages, contentplaceholder

I have a site with a few pages, and I'd like the titles of the pages to be:

```
Foo - 1st Page
Foo - 2nd Page
Foo - 3rd Page
```

I've created a Master Page with the following code:

```
<%@ Master Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Foo.master.cs" Inherits="Foo" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title>Foo - <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="SubTitle" runat="server"></asp:ContentPlaceHolder></title>
</head>
<body>
    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="MainContent" runat="server">
    </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
</body>
</html>
```

And then each page looks like this:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Foo.Master" %>
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="SubTitle" runat="server">1st Page</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">
    <a href="Page2.aspx">Page 2</a>
</asp:Content>
```

When I load the page in the browser I expect the title to be `Foo - 1st Page`, but it's just `1st Page`.

The html source is :

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head><title>
  1st Page
</title></head>
<body>

<a href="Page2.aspx">Page 2</a>

</body>
</html>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What are you seeing as the generated <title> tag?  (That's, to me anyhow, an unusual use of a placeholder.)  I'm wondering if a better solution might be to set the Page's Title property in the code-behind.

Comment: @ThatBlairGuy - I added the html source to my question.  Visual Studio's Master Page template has a ContentPlaceHolder called `title` in the title tag of the MasterPage.  I just added the `Foo - ` text before it, and renamed it to `SubTitle`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not want to remove `runat="server"` from `head`; it'll create other problems.

Use the following method which is a default method in ASP.Net Web Forms Application in Visual Studio 2012.

```
<!-- Master Page -->
<head runat="server">
    <title>Foo - <%: Page.Title %></title>
</head>

<!-- Content Page/xxx.aspx -->
<%@ Page Title="Home Page" ...>
```

Comment: Excellent. Thank you. For my purpose the lack of `runat="server"` wouldn't cause a problem (this is just a small group of test pages with nothing else in the `head`) but I've taken your suggestion because it makes the code simpler.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out this question had already been asked:  [ASP.NET: Having common Page title in master page with each page adding page-specific title?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3571618/asp-net-having-common-page-title-in-master-page-with-each-page-adding-page-spec)

After reading the answers there I found that removing `runat="server"` from the `head` element in the Master Page did the trick.